# Apache Ignite with Kudu

Tags: ignite

I am trying to position Ignite as Query Grid for databases such as Kudu, Hbase, etc.. Thus, all data silos will be queried over Ignite with read/write through. How this is possible? Are there any integrations with them?

- The first time, SQL query runs, it will need to pull the data from such databases and create the key/value on Ignite.
- Then, if one/two/three node goes down, eventually the data stored in memory will be lost. How the recovery is done or not possible?

Thanks
CK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Ignite SQL is unable to load specific data by query from external store, it's only possible on API `get()`/`getAll()` operations. To be able querying data you need load them into Ignite at first, for example, with [loadCache()](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteCache.html#loadCache-org.apache.ignite.lang.IgniteBiPredicate-java.lang.Object...-). Internally this function does a query to target database and transforms response into key-value manner.

BTW, if you enable [persistence](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/distributed-persistent-store) in Ignite, it will know the structure of data and will be able to query them, even if not all entries loaded into memory.

2. In case of node crash traditionally used data replication between nodes. In Ignite it's named [backups](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/primary-and-backup-copies). If you loose more nodes than backups set, then you'll need to preload data from store again.

Comment: So my understanding is, first load the data manually into cache - this is a distributed cache... which then Ignite can persist into disk with its own storage engine. Then, VoltDB could be direct competitor to Ignite giving the same features... Thx...

Comment: @CengizKayay VoltDB can only backup caches to disk, so the disk is a copy of the cache. Ignite, on the other hand, can utilize disk as a storage and store more data on disk than fits in a cache, so you are not limited by the size of the memory available.